# The falsifiability of natural selection

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, philosophy-of-science

I was wondering if we could think about experiments to falsify natural selection . According to [this wiki](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Falsifiability_of_evolution#cite_note-1) : we could invalidate natural selection

> “...if it could be shown that selection or environmental pressures do not
>   favor the reproductive success of better adapted individuals”.

So, to test this hypothesis we would have to:

- Have different individuals that are defined as more or less adapted to a given environment
- Put them in that environment
- See if the better adapted individuals have a better reproductive success. (I will avoid the word *fitness* because one can consider it already contains the principle of natural selection)

But is it possible to define *a priori* that an individual is more or less adapted? Of course, we could *suppose* a priori that because of some or other trait (higher longevity, higher stress tolerance, or whatever), an individual carrying that trait will be more adapted. But if we find out this individual does not have a better reproductive success in that environment, we could conclude it was just not the right trait to be better adapted and it would not invalidate natural selection.

Isn’t it, on the contrary, the fact that some individuals have a better reproductive success which allows defining them as better adapted *a posteriori*? There would then be some kind of a vicious circle.

Ok, so one could say that we do not need to define a priori better or less adapted individuals. We could just put individuals in an environment and see if at least *some* have a better reproductive success. That would mean that they are better adapted –and so that natural selection occurs-. But suppose we find no significant differences in individuals reproductive success: that could indeed mean that natural selection does not exist. But, well, that could also just mean that there was no selection pressure in that environment.

So if we want to test natural selection existence, we need either to get individuals that are a 100% sure better adapted than others; or environmental conditions that 100% sure exert selection pressures on organisms ; and we need to know this *a priori*. But, it seems to me that considering an individual as “adapted” or an environment as “selective” can only be done *a posteriori* **if we already accept the idea of natural selection**.

That’s why, to me, it is difficult to think of an experiment that would falsify natural selection. **Is natural selection falsifiable** ?

Comment: Short comment... Why do you think we have multi resistent bacteria? Let me tell you why... we are selecting those few in a group with higher resistance everytime we expose the group to an antibiotic.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that I'll edit my post. Just to be clear however : I never implied that anything sucked and I never doubted about natural selection's validity. This was just a serious question about its epistemological status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is natural selection?**

Natural Selection (NS) is an evolutionary process causing a directional change in both a phenotypic trait and the allele frequencies associated with particular values of this phenotypic trait whenever there is a trait that

1. Has a non-zero narrow-sense heritability $h_N^2$

   - See [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42273/why-is-a-heritability-coefficient-not-an-index-of-how-genetic-something-is) for the definition of heritability
   - Note that if $h_N^2 ≠ 0$, then it necessarily implies that the trait is variable in the population.
2. Correlate with fitness variance in the population

   - See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) for the definition of correlation

You may want to have a look at [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/is-there-a-biological-mechanism-for-evolution-encoded-into-our-dna) (maybe in particular Lewontin's recipe explained in [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/is-there-a-biological-mechanism-for-evolution-encoded-into-our-dna/20914#20914)) or have a look at an intro course to evolution such as [Understanding Evolution](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) by UC Berkeley if this is unclear to you.

You may also want to have a look at the post [How is “selection” best defined?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60587/how-is-selection-best-defined)

**Note about the environment**

Note that the genotype - fitness covariance does not necessarily need to be dependent or correlated with a specific environmental variable. Many selection pressures are indeed independent of the environment. If one specific genotype is associated to heart failure, then the environment may matter little. This genotype will always be associated with lower fitness.

In other words, you do not need environmental change, or environment specific adaptations in mind to test NS.

**Would evidence that what is needed for natural selection to happen does not exist falsify NS?**

*Mutations*

I don't think that an evidence that mutations do not occur would falsify NS because while NS needs genetic variation (fuelled by mutations), the process per say does not refer to the creation of new genetic variance via mutations. Showing that mutation do not occur would not per say falsify NS (I think) but it would make the point that NS cannot happen. A bit like, the absence of energy would not falsify the theory of gravity but it would prevents any gravity to ever happen.

The theory of evolution as whole would be falsified if one were to show mutations never occur (or occur at a much lower or much higher rate than currently observed) though.

*Heritability*

Similarly, if one could show that $h_N^2 = 0$ for all traits (nothing is heritable), then this would also prevent any NS to ever happen

*Fitness variance*

Similarly, if one could show that there is no fitness variance in population or even that fitness is always independent of the gentic variance (in other words, fitness itself is not heritable), then NS would never happen.

**How to falsify natural selection?**

You could show that for a phenotypic trait $h_N^2 > 0$ and show that genetic variance correlates with fitness variance (fitness can be measured as the number of offsprings) and yet repeatedly fail to see any change in the phenotypic trait values (or frequency of the loci explaining variance for this trait) over time. Such observations would falsify NS.

Comment: I think my difficulty comes from the fact that it is hard to think a situation in which a heritable trait which provides fitness benefits would not bring to a change in genotypic or phenotypic frequency associated to this trait over time. I wonder if theoretical models have shown this possible.

Comment: Well, no, I don't think a theoretical model has shown the opposite possible. But it is not because a cause to consequence is too easy to grasp that it makes its formulation unfalsifiable. All our models have been developed following some logical cause-consequence relationships. Some are hard to get an intuition from. NS has the advantage to be a fairly simple mechanism, easy to understand even for a layman.

Comment: I also wonder about something you said: can environnent really be independent on the genotype-fitness covariance ? If you put a terrestrial mammal with a heart failure gene and one without it at the bottom of the sea, they'll both have null fitness. Put them both in a futuristic world where every disease is cured before birth, they will have the same positive fitness.

Comment: The genotype-fitness covariance is measured on an existing population. You cannot observe the effect of extreme environments not explored by the species range. But I agree this can be misleading. Of course, genotype-fitness covariance would necessarily be dependent upon the environment but not necessarily upon the experienced environment.

Comment: @Remi.b This is a good definition, but where in this definition is an ability to distinguish between natural selection and genetic drift?

Comment: @Remi.b Depending upon how you define "directional", there can be genetic drift responsible for "a directional change in both a phenotypic trait and the allele frequencies associated with particular values of this phenotypic trait" with the trait having non-zero heritability and being correlated with fitness variance.

Comment: @Remi.b Do I not have comment-editing privileges?  To clarify what I mean when I say that there can be genetic drift responsible for a directional change in both a phenotypic trait and the allele frequencies associated with particular values of this phenotypic trait" with the trait having non-zero heritability and being correlated with fitness variance. If you determine that evolution by drift is responsible for a trait (or a modification of the fixated trait), this is consistent with: directional change in both trait & allele, non-zero heritability, and a correlation with fitness variance.

Comment: Genetic drift is a stochastic process. So, yes at any given instance the change goes in a certain direction but if you were to replicate the process, then if genetic drift alone is considered, you should have on average no effect on the phenotype and allele frequency.

Comment: I don't know why I wasn't notified of this reply.  So, I think what you are saying is that selection comes with an *expectation* that there is a change in frequency, such that the population is better able to manage the selective pressure in the future than it was before the selection.

Comment: The change brought by selection are a change in allele frequency. NS does not necessarily increase the survival probability of the lineage (or whatever you mean by `the population is better able to manage the selective pressure in the future`).

Comment: @Remi.b, why does it not necessarily increase the survival probability of the lineage?  (Hold aside sexual selection and I mean increase the survival probability in comparison to if the selection had not occurred, so hold aside Van Valen's red queen representation.)

Comment: I can't answer all your questions in comments (here and on other posts). This last question takes quite a bit of time to address and more text that can fit in a reasonable number of comments anyway. Please ask your questions in new posts.

Comment: @Remi.b OK, thank you.  I will ask that question.

Comment: @Kjian That is just evidence that NS is the correct interpretation, it is like saying under what conditions gravity could be shown not to be true, the conditions only need to be hypothetical but recognizable and testable. That is the difference between falsifiability and falsification.

Comment: @John Yeah that was my question actually - are there testable conditions that could show it not to be true - I don't think it would actually, I was just wondering if such conditions could exist.

Comment: @Kjian yes for instance if you could show all population's gene pool never changed across all generations, even if conditions were changed in many many different ways.